# How to get the a href tag value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that has an InnerHTML for "a href" tag define in the .cs file as shown below.

```
HtmlGenericControl _divToolTipContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
_divToolTipContainer.ID = string.Format("divToolTipContainer.{0}", item.ID.ToString());
_divToolTipContainer.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('" + btnItemThumbnail.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "','')\">" +
                                       itemimage;
```

Now I want to get the a href value in the javascript. So have this code:

```
var a = document.getElementById(oElementId);
alert( a.href );
```

But the value being retrieve is "undefined."

So what is the proper way?

Comment: Are you sure that `oElementId` exists?  What is it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Doesn't matter, the Javascript would fail, not provide `undefined` if `oElementId` doesn't exist. The result of `document.getElementById` would be `null`, and `null.href` is an error

Comment: @Teemu That is ASP.NET code, it's not directly related. They're just showing how the element is being generated, I'm guessing...

Comment: @Ian it still matters what it is though.  What if it doesn't have `href`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills True, but you were questioning if it exists. I guess the important question is "What is it?" as you also asked :) , as I would agree it's probably finding a different element without the `href` attribute

Comment: is this happening during page load? where did you keep the script?

Comment: Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fJWh2/

Comment: @ExplosionPills I bet the `oElementId` refers to the `<div>` they create in the ASP.NET, so they need to get its child `<a>` element (used in the `.InnerHtml`)

Comment: `var a = document.getElementById(oElementId);` is not working because the `oElementId` should not be the good identifier. Be careful with ASP.NET because the framework manage the HTML, and the id may be a generated id, not the one you imagine. Use firebug to check that point first. Secondly, check if there is a clientId property on the div you have created. Maybe you should use this information to retrieve the child `<a>`

Comment: @user1073122 If that were the problem (`oElementId` holds an incorrect `id`), then there would be a Javascript error - the OP said the code works but gets `undefined`. That's not a Javascript error. Nonetheless, I agree that it's important to use the `.ClientId` property, but how do we know what the value of `oElementId` really is? You can't just jump to conclusions. Firebug would definitely help, but I don't think the OP has done any debugging...

Answer (score 1):

Try printing Element `a` in console

```
var a = document.getElementById(oElementId);
console.log( a );
```

and see what you get there. Also, did you try `getAttribute`?

```
alert(a.getAttribute('href'));
```